# Expected sum of $m$ tickets.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

If $m$ tickets are drawn at random out of $n$ tickets which are numbered from $1$ to $n$, find the expected sum.

How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint

number of tickets drawn $\times$ expected average value of each ticket

Comment: IE: Use the Linearity of Expectation.

Comment: @GrahamKemp +1 : good assist